# arima model, missing values

Tags: r, modeling, arima

I am trying to estimate a quarterly arima model that explains the VIX index by one or more variables. My problem is that I need to difference and use log of my variables but because the dataset has some missing values, I get that lengths of 'x' and 'xreg' do not match. Below is a glimpse of my dataset:
[image]

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
y2 <- diff(log((histdata$VIX)))
y3 <- diff(log((histdata$SP500)))
y4 <- diff(log((histdata$NASDAQ)))
y5 <- diff(log((histdata$LIBOR3M)))
y6 <- diff(log((histdata$CPI)))
y7 <- diff(log((histdata$HPI)))
y8 <- diff(log((histdata$CDS5Y)))

arima(histdata$VIX, order = c(1, 1, 1),
     seasonal = list(order = c(0L,0L, 0L), period = 4),
     xreg = c(y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8))
```

I would need to somehow pick the correct length of the variables and estimate it at quarterly frequency.

Thanks,
Ilias

Comment: If you have missing data I recommend imputation instead of using different variable lengths in your model. Imputation means replacing missing values with a value that makes sense in context (mean, max, zero, etc...) Here is some info to get you started: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/62408/53760

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am not supposed to impute the missing values.

Comment: In that case I would build two ARIMA models - one for each length of the data that you have and then compare or merge the results. I don't think there is a way to use variables of different lengths in the same ARIMA model.